# Нужны ли кавычки в названии географического объекта, если рядом стоит слово «название»?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, топонимика

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужно ли брать в кавычки непосредственно название географического объекта (города в примере), если рядом стоит слово «название»?
*Название «Ярград» произошло от...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что здесь можно применить вот это [правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169) Розенталя:

> выделяются кавычками слова, разъясняющие термины, выражения (*в значении*, *в смысле* и т. п.): *раскрыть понятие «дуализм».*

В вашем случае слово «название» можно считать родовым словом, а топоним — приложением:
город Ярград — название «Ярград» — название *Ярград* (с использованием курсива).

> Мы часто слышим название «Ревель», оно пришло к нам из немецкого языка и является производным от местности Rävala.

Comment: Спасибо, Риммочка!

Comment: Ой! Растерялась даже... Риммочка... Пожалуйста.