# Нужны ли то кавычки-с?

Tags: кавычки

В данном случае нужны кавычки или нет?

`Есть и вправду деревня с названием «Чоботы», а то, что есть фамилия «Чорный», – это тоже правда.`

Comment: Дубль. Пользуйтесь «Поиском по сайту»! https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462422/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужны ли кавычки в названии географического объекта, если рядом стоит слово «название»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462422/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Есть и вправду деревня с названием **«Чоботы»**, а то, что есть фамилия **"Чорный"**, – это тоже правда.*

Но: *Моя фамилия ***Чорный***.*

**Примеры:**

— *У меня будет в руках газета. Моя **фамилия Миколайчук**. — Зачем мне ваша фамилия?*

В конце концов — они могли скромно намекнуть начальству, что сегодня понедельник, а не пятница, то есть фамилия **Бомштейна** вообще не должна упоминаться.

— Да Эн-Эн не фамилия, а так — метка: «узнавай, мол, сам, кто я. ..» Вот у этого старичка есть **фамилия. «Этюд»**.

Comment: You should use the same quotes.

Comment: Предлагаю вам дополнить ответ, чтобы была причина, почему так. И интересно, почеиу вы используете разные кавычки. В общем, дополните ответ, чтоб все знали, почему именно так.